# Como iterar uma lista no Flask

Tags: html, python, aplicação-web, flask, jinja2

Eu tenho esse código no Flask (que usa o Jinja2)

```
{%block content%}
    {% for i in posts %}
        {% set x = x + 1 -%}
        <p style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px 5px; border-radius: 5px;">{{ i[x] }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('redirectposts') }}">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Posts</button>
    </form>
{%endblock%}
```

- O x nesse trecho começa como 0

```
return render_template('index.html', titulo="Home", posts=lista, x = 0)
```

'Posts' recebe uma lists com algumas tuplas.. O problema é que eu não consigo iterar o 'posts' e colocar as tuplas nos parágrafos (cada tupla em um parágrafo separado, indo do 1ª indice até o ultimo, como é o esperado), ao invés disso, ele sempre retorna um "p" como todas as tuplas de vez.
Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa noite.
Eu acho que o ideal seria você fazer o seguinte:

```
{%block content%}
    {% for i in posts %}
        {% for i2 in i %}
           <p style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px 5px; border-radius: 5px;">{{ i2 }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('redirectposts') }}">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Posts</button>
    </form>
{%endblock%}
```